# How to intercept the top right "X"

Tags: python, pyqt5

Each window has an "X" symbol at the top right which immediately closes the active application.
I have a QFileDialog like this

```
     dir = "hdb1/temp/"
     options = QFileDialog.Options()
     options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
     try:
        fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "/hdb1/temp/", "File type (*.pdf)",options=options)
     except Error as e:
         do something
     fsize = os.path.getsize(fname)
```

If I decide to press the "X" above I can't intercept the event and the whole application crashes

Comment: Just do something like `if not fname: return`

Comment: crash occours before the intercept or Error is not the correct kind of error to intercept

Comment: The crash occurs because `os.path.getsize()` raises a `FileNotFoundError` because `fname` is an empty string when you close the file dialog.

Comment: You are right, my fault. Didn't read carefully the whole report.  Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Do something like

```
event.ignore()  # Ignore the close event initially
    try:
        fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "/hdb1/temp/", "File type (*.pdf)")
        if fname:
            fsize = os.path.getsize(fname)
        event.accept()  # Accept the close event after handling the file

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle the exception or display an error message
        print("An error occurred:", str(e))
```

We can ignore the close event by calling **event.ignore()** to handle it ourselves.

Comment: Locic is correct but both `events` or `Event` dont have .ignore attribute
`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ignore'`

Comment: @RyanDay I believe the OP thought that you were trying to intercept the [`closeEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent) of a window and show a dialog before actually closing it. In that case, `event` would be the QCloseEvent argument of the above `closeEvent()` function, but calling `accept()` would be pointless since a QCloseEvent is already accepted by default when the event handler receives it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).